# I installed Windows 10 WoR on my RPi 3 B but the sound coming through the headphone jack is playing in a higher pitch

Tags: windows

I was trying to play a song that worked fine but the sound comes out higher-pitched sped up a little. Is this a common issue, how can I fix it?

Comment: Windows 10 WoA is long dead. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry I meant WoR

Comment: Then this is probably the wrong place to ask this type of question. I doubt even 1% of the people here have ever even used Windows 10 WoR. Probably better asking [here](https://www.worproject.ml/bugtracker/my_view_page.php).